# Postfix - receive mails in user account

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, mx-record, gmail, email

I have successfully installed and configured `postfix` mail server, and I can now send mail from my `user account` mail to another `email` on the net, through `Gmail`.

What I want to achieve: is to send mails in the opposite direction; from `Gmail` to my `user account`. I have a `domain name`, but to redirect `incoming mails`, I guess that I need to configure my `MX` record.

What's the easiest way to configure it?

Answer (score 0):

You set mx entries by adding some line in file name named.local,

That file will be in

```
"/var/named/domains/named.local".
```

may this file on different location in your case, Open that file.

You should see a line in there MX record.

```
example.com.        IN      MX  10   mail.example.com.
```

edit this and place your mx entries, if you are using Google mail, then search for Google mx record, and update it..

Comment: on my `Opensuse` machine, `bind` configuration files are located in `/var/lib/names/`, and I cant find the file `named.local`. For Gmail, I have to add all MX records in [Configuring Your MX Records](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=33915)?

Comment: I have found the configuration file `/var/lib/named/etc/named.conf.include`. And I have added a zone (`/var/lib/named/<domain>.zone`) which point `MX records` to Gmail's ones, but I doesnt show me anything in `response section` with the command `dig mx <domain>`.

Answer (score 0):

- I see with `netstat -antp` that my `port 25` is opened.
- And when I send an email from `Gmail`, using the command `tcpdump -i wlan0 dst host 192.168.0.100 and dst port 25` on the server, I can see an incoming connection to the `postfix` mail server from `mail-pb0-f65.google.com.58369` with a `Syn` flag, but no response from my `mail server`.
- But Gmail is reporting me a mail error: `The recipient server did not accept our requests to connect. [IP address]:25: Connection refused]`.

So, I concluded that it was my `ISP` who blocked `port 25`, am I right ?

What I found strange is that I havent configured my `MX record`, but `Gmail` achieved to brind the `Syn` packet to my `mail server`. I guess that it resolve `mail domain` (the part after the `@`) to `A record` when the `MX record` isn't defined.

Here is the output of `iptables -vnL` as requested:

Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  415  205K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
30311   29M ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            ctstate RELATED
  462 24482 input_ext  all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-IN-ILL-TARGET "
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 LOG        all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-FWD-ILL-ROUTING "

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 32145 packets, 3921K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
  415  205K ACCEPT     all  --  *      lo      0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain forward_ext (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain input_ext (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
   38  2964 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PKTTYPE = broadcast
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 4
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            icmptype 8
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:25 flags:0x17/0x02 LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP "
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:25
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp dpt:80 flags:0x17/0x02 LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-INext-ACC-TCP "
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:80
   19  2306 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PKTTYPE = multicast
    0     0 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            PKTTYPE = broadcast
    0     0 LOG        tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 tcp flags:0x17/0x02 LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
    0     0 LOG        icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
    0     0 LOG        udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            limit: avg 3/min burst 5 ctstate NEW LOG flags 6 level 4 prefix "SFW2-INext-DROP-DEFLT "
  405 19212 DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0

Chain reject_func (0 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with tcp-reset
    0     0 REJECT     udp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

Comment: I would need your iptables configuration to help you (`iptables -vnL`). `netstat -antp` cannot directly really show you "open ports". It can show you current TCP connections, and their state.
Do you have iptables OUTPUT DROP default policy? If yes, you would need to allow TCP responses to port 25.
If your firewall is correctly set up, it could be your ISP which is blocking port 25 for spam fighting purposes.

Comment: I have added the output of `iptables -vnL` above, and I see a `DROP ALL` on the 2nd line of `Chain input_text`.